# 22.04 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish) network manager loses link to wifi

Tags: networking, network-manager

it all works after a reboot.
After some time -- no network access.
Ubuntu os shows wifi connected.
My modem shows wifi connected.
Best I can figure the Ubuntu Network manager loses the link to the wifi port.
Any idea how to fix this?

Dump from non operational state

###### wireless info START

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy

###### kernel

Linux 5.19.0-45-generic #46~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Wed Jun 7 15:06:04 UTC 20 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

###### desktop Ubuntu

###### lspci

00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:7a70] (rev 11)
DeviceName: Onboard - Ethernet
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0094]
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller [10ec:8125] (rev 05)
Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller [1458:e000]
Kernel driver in use: r8169

###### rfkill

0: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no

###### lsmod

iwlmvm                610304  0
mac80211             1323008  1 iwlmvm
libarc4                16384  1 mac80211
iwlwifi               503808  1 iwlmvm
gigabyte_wmi           20480  0
wmi_bmof               16384  0
cfg80211             1052672  3 iwlmvm,iwlwifi,mac80211
wmi                    32768  2 gigabyte_wmi,wmi_bmof

###### ifconfig

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
link/loopback  brd 
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 ::1/128 scope host
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp2s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
link/ether <MAC 'enp2s0' [IF1]> brd 
3: wlo1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether <MAC 'wlo1' [IF2]> brd 
altname wlp0s20f3
inet6 fd90:fd81:7de4:1:dc88:16ee:94fc:799a/64 scope global temporary dynamic
valid_lft 524962sec preferred_lft 6377sec
inet6 fd90:fd81:7de4:1:a35c:2f9b:ffc:aaf3/64 scope global temporary deprecated dynamic
valid_lft 438749sec preferred_lft 0sec
inet6 fd90:fd81:7de4:1:e3c6:90db:daf8:37c6/64 scope global temporary deprecated dynamic
valid_lft 352537sec preferred_lft 0sec
inet6 fd90:fd81:7de4:1:531c:36c5:6b93:83cd/64 scope global temporary deprecated dynamic
valid_lft 266324sec preferred_lft 0sec
inet6 fd90:fd81:7de4:1:7493:7a3f:6048:fdb9/64 scope global temporary deprecated dynamic
valid_lft 180110sec preferred_lft 0sec
inet6 fd90:fd81:7de4:1:9425:32af:d7ae:cbb9/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute
valid_lft 2591974sec preferred_lft 604774sec
inet6 fe80::d864:f68c:fc17:60f7/64 scope link noprefixroute
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: vboxnet0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
link/ether <MAC 'vboxnet0' [IF3]> brd

###### iwconfig

lo        no wireless extensions.
enp2s0    no wireless extensions.
vboxnet0  no wireless extensions.

wlo1      IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"Doom"
Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.805 GHz  Access Point: <MAC 'Doom' [AC1]>
Bit Rate=29.2 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm
Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
Power Management:on
Link Quality=56/70  Signal level=-54 dBm
Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:3068   Missed beacon:0

###### route

###### resolv.conf

[777 root '/etc/resolv.conf' -> '../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf']

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search .

###### network managers

Installed: NetworkManager

Running:
root         827       1  0 Jun20 ?        00:08:46 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

###### NetworkManager info

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlo1
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceWifi
GENERAL.DBUS-PATH:                      /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/3
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Intel Corporation
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        --
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         iwlwifi
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 5.19.0-45-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               72.daa05125.0 so-a0-gf-a0-72.uc
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'wlo1' [IF2]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.IP4-CONNECTIVITY:               1 (none)
GENERAL.IP6-CONNECTIVITY:               3 (limited)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.3/net/wlo1
GENERAL.PATH:                           pci-0000:00:14.3
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       wlo1
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Doom
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       49c47c28-6e20-4f41-b482-302477807413
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/4
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     29 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.UP:                     yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.LOWER-UP:               yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.CARRIER:                yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.PROMISC:                no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WEP:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA2:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.TKIP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.CCMP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.AP:                     yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.ADHOC:                  yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.2GHZ:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.5GHZ:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.MESH:                   no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.IBSS-RSN:               yes
IP4.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fd90:fd81:7de4:1:dc88:16ee:94fc:799a/64
IP6.ADDRESS[2]:                         fd90:fd81:7de4:1:a35c:2f9b:ffc:aaf3/64
IP6.ADDRESS[3]:                         fd90:fd81:7de4:1:e3c6:90db:daf8:37c6/64
IP6.ADDRESS[4]:                         fd90:fd81:7de4:1:531c:36c5:6b93:83cd/64
IP6.ADDRESS[5]:                         fd90:fd81:7de4:1:7493:7a3f:6048:fdb9/64
IP6.ADDRESS[6]:                         fd90:fd81:7de4:1:9425:32af:d7ae:cbb9/64
IP6.ADDRESS[7]:                         fe80::d864:f68c:fc17:60f7/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            fe80::8670:d7ff:feba:acf2
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = fd90:fd81:7de4:1::/64, nh = ::, mt = 600
IP6.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 1024
IP6.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = ::/0, nh = fe80::8670:d7ff:feba:acf2, mt = 20600
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/1
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   49c47c28-6e20-4f41-b482-302477807413 | Doom

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         p2p-dev-wlo1
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi-p2p
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceWifiP2P
GENERAL.DBUS-PATH:                      /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/8
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         --
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        --
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         (unknown)
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 --
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               --
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         (unknown)
GENERAL.MTU:                            0
GENERAL.STATE:                          30 (disconnected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.IP4-CONNECTIVITY:               1 (none)
GENERAL.IP6-CONNECTIVITY:               1 (none)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /virtual/device/placeholder/6
GENERAL.PATH:                           --
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       --
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.UP:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.LOWER-UP:               no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.CARRIER:                no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.PROMISC:                no
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: --

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp2s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.DBUS-PATH:                      /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8169
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 5.19.0-45-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               --
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enp2s0' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.REASON:                         2 (Device is now managed)
GENERAL.IP4-CONNECTIVITY:               1 (none)
GENERAL.IP6-CONNECTIVITY:               1 (none)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.2/0000:02:00.0/net/enp2s0
GENERAL.PATH:                           pci-0000:02:00.0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       --
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.UP:                     yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.LOWER-UP:               no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.CARRIER:                no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.PROMISC:                no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               off
IP4.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: --

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         vboxnet0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.DBUS-PATH:                      /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/5
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         --
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        --
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         vboxnet
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 7.0.8
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               0xA2CDE001
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'vboxnet0' [IF3]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          10 (unmanaged)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.IP4-CONNECTIVITY:               0 (unknown)
GENERAL.IP6-CONNECTIVITY:               0 (unknown)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/virtual/net/vboxnet0
GENERAL.PATH:                           --
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       vboxnet0
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     no
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.UP:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.LOWER-UP:               no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.CARRIER:                no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.PROMISC:                no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               off
IP4.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: --

SSID                    BSSID              MODE   CHAN  FREQ      RATE        SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY          ACTIVE  IN-USE
--                      <MAC '' [AC15]>  Infra  36    5180 MHz  130 Mbit/s  95      ▂▄▆█  WPA2              no
Doom                    <MAC 'Doom' [AC1]>  Infra  161   5805 MHz  540 Mbit/s  77      ▂▄▆_  WPA2              yes     *
Doom                    <MAC 'Doom' [AC4]>  Infra  5     2432 MHz  270 Mbit/s  74      ▂▄▆_  WPA2              no
Doom                    <MAC 'Doom' [AC5]>  Infra  40    5200 MHz  270 Mbit/s  59      ▂▄▆_  WPA2              no

###### NetworkManager.state

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

###### NetworkManager config

[[/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf]]
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 3

[[/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf]]
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
[ifupdown]
managed=false
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-dns-resolved.conf]]
[main]
dns=systemd-resolved

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf]]
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:gsm,except:type:cdma

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/20-connectivity-ubuntu.conf]]
[connectivity]
uri=http://connectivity-check.ubuntu.com./

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/no-mac-addr-change.conf]]
[device-31-mac-addr-change]
match-device=driver:eagle_sdio,driver:wl
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

###### NetworkManager profiles

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Doom.nmconnection]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Doom | type=wifi
[wifi] ssid=Doom
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

###### Netplan config

[/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml]
network:
version: 2
renderer: NetworkManager

###### iwlist channels

lo        no frequency information.
enp2s0    no frequency information.
vboxnet0  no frequency information.

wlo1      32 channels in total; available frequencies :
Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
Channel 36 : 5.18 GHz
Channel 40 : 5.2 GHz
Channel 44 : 5.22 GHz
Channel 48 : 5.24 GHz
Channel 52 : 5.26 GHz
Channel 56 : 5.28 GHz
Channel 60 : 5.3 GHz
Channel 64 : 5.32 GHz
Channel 100 : 5.5 GHz
Channel 104 : 5.52 GHz
Channel 108 : 5.54 GHz
Channel 112 : 5.56 GHz
Channel 116 : 5.58 GHz
Channel 120 : 5.6 GHz
Channel 124 : 5.62 GHz
Channel 128 : 5.64 GHz
Channel 132 : 5.66 GHz
Channel 136 : 5.68 GHz
Channel 140 : 5.7 GHz
Current Frequency:5.805 GHz

###### iwlist scan

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.
enp2s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.
vboxnet0  Interface doesn't support scanning.

Channel occupancy:

```
  6   APs on   Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
  1   APs on   Frequency:2.417 GHz (Channel 2)
  6   APs on   Frequency:2.432 GHz (Channel 5)
  1   APs on   Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
  4   APs on   Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
  1   APs on   Frequency:5.18 GHz (Channel 36)
  3   APs on   Frequency:5.2 GHz (Channel 40)
  3   APs on   Frequency:5.785 GHz
  1   APs on   Frequency:5.805 GHz
```

###### module infos

[iwlmvm]
filename:       /lib/modules/5.19.0-45-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/mvm/iwlmvm.ko
license:        GPL
description:    The new Intel(R) wireless AGN driver for Linux
depends:        mac80211,cfg80211,iwlwifi
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           iwlmvm
vermagic:       5.19.0-45-generic SMP preempt mod_unload modversions
parm:           init_dbg:set to true to debug an ASSERT in INIT fw (default: false (bool)
parm:           power_scheme:power management scheme: 1-active, 2-balanced, 3-low power, default: 2 (int)

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/5.19.0-45-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
depends:        cfg80211,libarc4
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           mac80211
vermagic:       5.19.0-45-generic SMP preempt mod_unload modversions
parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta. (bool)
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[iwlwifi]
filename:       /lib/modules/5.19.0-45-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
license:        GPL
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
depends:        cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           iwlwifi
vermagic:       5.19.0-45-generic SMP preempt mod_unload modversions
parm:           swcrypto:using crypto in software (default 0 [hardware]) (int)
parm:           11n_disable:disable 11n functionality, bitmap: 1: full, 2: disable agg TX, 4: disable agg RX, 8 enable agg TX (uint)
parm:           amsdu_size:amsdu size 0: 12K for multi Rx queue devices, 2K for AX210 devices, 4K for other devices 1:4K 2:8K 3:12K (16K buffers) 4: 2K (default 0) (int)
parm:           fw_restart:restart firmware in case of error (default true) (bool)
parm:           nvm_file:NVM file name (charp)
parm:           uapsd_disable:disable U-APSD functionality bitmap 1: BSS 2: P2P Client (default: 3) (uint)
parm:           enable_ini:0:disable, 1-15:FW_DBG_PRESET Values, 16:enabled without preset value defined,Debug INI TLV FW debug infrastructure (default: 16)
parm:           bt_coex_active:enable wifi/bt co-exist (default: enable) (bool)
parm:           led_mode:0=system default, 1=On(RF On)/Off(RF Off), 2=blinking, 3=Off (default: 0) (int)
parm:           power_save:enable WiFi power management (default: disable) (bool)
parm:           power_level:default power save level (range from 1 - 5, default: 1) (int)
parm:           disable_11ac:Disable VHT capabilities (default: false) (bool)
parm:           remove_when_gone:Remove dev from PCIe bus if it is deemed inaccessible (default: false) (bool)
parm:           disable_11ax:Disable HE capabilities (default: false) (bool)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/5.19.0-45-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
depends:
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           cfg80211
vermagic:       5.19.0-45-generic SMP preempt mod_unload modversions
parm:           bss_entries_limit:limit to number of scan BSS entries (per wiphy, default 1000) (int)
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

###### module parameters

[iwlmvm]
init_dbg: N
power_scheme: 2

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
minstrel_vht_only: Y
probe_wait_ms: 500

grep: /sys/module/iwlwifi/parameters/enable_ini: Operation not permitted
[iwlwifi]
11n_disable: 0
amsdu_size: 0
bt_coex_active: Y
disable_11ac: N
disable_11ax: N
fw_restart: Y
led_mode: 0
nvm_file: (null)
power_level: 0
power_save: N
remove_when_gone: N
swcrypto: 0
uapsd_disable: 3

[cfg80211]
bss_entries_limit: 1000
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

###### modprobe options

[/etc/modprobe.d/amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi 
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) 
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

###### dmesg

[497618.382774] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00080401 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[497618.382780] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00400410 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[497618.382806] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00080401 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[497618.382813] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00400410 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[497618.382841] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00009061 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[497618.382871] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000061 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[497618.383032] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 4 fired (delay=0ms).
[504313.821689] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Microcode SW error detected. Restarting 0x0.
[504313.821798] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[504313.821803] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Transport status: 0x0000004A, valid: 6
[504313.821809] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 72.daa05125.0 so-a0-gf-a0-72.ucode
[504313.821814] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000071 | NMI_INTERRUPT_UMAC_FATAL
[504313.821820] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00008200 | trm_hw_status0
[504313.821824] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1
[504313.821828] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x004DAAEE | branchlink2
[504313.821831] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x004B9A80 | interruptlink1
[504313.821835] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x004B9A80 | interruptlink2
[504313.821838] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000B852 | data1
[504313.821841] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000010 | data2
[504313.821845] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | data3
[504313.821848] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xD90163AF | beacon time
[504313.821852] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA81F2EE3 | tsf low
[504313.821855] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x000000B0 | tsf hi
[504313.821858] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | time gp1
[504313.821862] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x8F0D8894 | time gp2
[504313.821865] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000001 | uCode revision type
[504313.821869] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000048 | uCode version major
[504313.821872] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xDAA05125 | uCode version minor
[504313.821875] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000430 | hw version
[504313.821879] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00C89002 | board version
[504313.821882] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x800CFC03 | hcmd
[504313.821885] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x24020000 | isr0
[504313.821889] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr1
[504313.821892] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x48F80002 | isr2
[504313.821895] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00C3681F | isr3
[504313.821898] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr4
[504313.821901] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0208001C | last cmd Id
[504313.821905] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000B852 | wait_event
[504313.821908] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000024 | l2p_control
[504313.821911] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00018034 | l2p_duration
[504313.821915] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000000F | l2p_mhvalid
[504313.821918] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x08C700D8 | l2p_addr_match
[504313.821922] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000009 | lmpm_pmg_sel
[504313.821925] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | timestamp
[504313.821928] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x000050A4 | flow_handler
[504313.821976] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[504313.821979] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Transport status: 0x0000004A, valid: 7
[504313.821983] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20003463 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT
[504313.821988] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1
[504313.821991] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x8045FDF8 | umac branchlink2
[504313.821995] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0081568 | umac interruptlink1
[504313.821998] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac interruptlink2
[504313.822001] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA81F2ED5 | umac data1
[504313.822005] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x8F0D8885 | umac data2
[504313.822008] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x19B09267 | umac data3
[504313.822011] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000048 | umac major
[504313.822014] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xDAA05125 | umac minor
[504313.822017] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x8F0D888D | frame pointer
[504313.822020] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0885DF8 | stack pointer
[504313.822023] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0088010D | last host cmd
[504313.822027] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr status reg
[504313.822054] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: IML/ROM dump:
[504313.822057] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000B03 | IML/ROM error/state
[504313.822087] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00008338 | IML/ROM data1
[504313.822120] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000090 | IML/ROM WFPM_AUTH_KEY_0
[504313.822150] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Fseq Registers:
[504313.822177] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x60000100 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[504313.822183] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x003D0003 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[504313.822208] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00190002 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[504313.822214] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000A652 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[504313.822240] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000003 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[504313.822245] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x4552414E | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[504313.822271] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00080401 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[504313.822276] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00400410 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[504313.822302] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00080401 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[504313.822310] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00400410 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[504313.822337] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00009061 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[504313.822367] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000061 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[504313.822542] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 4 fired (delay=0ms).

Comment: So far things seem to be working. There was an update just prior to June 30 that (so far) cured my wifi problems.
I also found this command on Launchpad.net.

echo "options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=0 swcrypto=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwififix.conf > /dev/null

It creates the file iwlwififix.conf in /etc/modprobe.d with the contents of the echo command. Supposedly it transfers decription from the wifi driver to the CPU.

I applied both update and this command at the same time, but verifying found out that wifi stays put with just the updates.